# sending data from sharedpreferences to database in web

Tags: android, database, web

I want to send data to my website which is saved in SharedPreferences of android application. Is it possible? Can anybody give me one example?

Thanks in advance! :D

Answer (score 0):

What I'd do is use the [`getAll`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#getAll%28%29) method to fetch the preferences, serialize the resulting Map using something like [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) and send it using http to your website (using a rest service or something like that)

Comment: I'd only suggest that "send it using http" should be rephrased as use [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).